# Copy container by Azure CLI and wait for result

Tags: azure, azure-cli

I tried to find some simple way how to copy container from one storage to other asynchronously via Azure CLI. Something that can be done by azcopy. I don't have azcopy on my machine installed, but Azure CLI is.

Question: **I understand I need to copy one blob after other. How do I check that the copy operation is finished?**

---

Something that kind of works, but calling `az storage blob show` one by one takes very long time (minutes).

```
$backup = 'somecontainer'
$exists = (az storage container exists --name $backup --account-name an --account-key ak --output tsv) -match 'true'

if (!$exists) {
  az storage container create --name $backup --account-name mt --account-key mk
}

$blobs = az storage blob list --container-name $backup  --account-name an --account-key ak | ConvertFrom-Json

# copy one by one
$blobs.name | % { 
  $name = $_
  az storage blob copy start --destination-blob $name --destination-container $backup --source-blob $name --source-container $backup   --account-name mt --account-key mk --source-account-name an --source-account-key ak 
}

# check operation status
$results = $blobs.name | % { 
  az storage blob show --container-name $backup --name $_ --account-name mt --account-key mk | ConvertFrom-Json
}

# still unfinished copy opearations:
$results | ? { !($_.properties.copy.completiontime) } | % { $_.name }
```

Comment: You could try with [copy start-batch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/storage/blob/copy?view=azure-cli-latest#az-storage-blob-copy-start-batch).

Answer (score 0):

@stej As @GeorgeChen mentioned you can use the below:

```
az storage blob copy start-batch --account-key 00000000 --account-name MyAccount --destination-container MyDestinationContainer --source-account-key MySourceKey --source-account-name MySourceAccount --source-container MySourceContainer
```

Here is the documentation link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/storage/blob/copy?view=azure-cli-latest#az-storage-blob-copy-start-batch